# flutter: Make layers of CustomPaint drawing complement each other instead of blending into each other

Tags: flutter, dart, custom-painting

I'm painting two layers of graphs on one `CustomPaint`. The first will occlude over half of the second layer.

## Problem

Currently I just paint the first data and then second data using two `Paint`s, with their `blendMode` set.

This creates an overlay of two data, which blends. But I don't need the blend, just the area of difference to be painted using the second `Paint`, i.e., a complementary composite view.

On the performance side, I don't know if blending would have internal optimization to avoid drawing the occluded part.

Reference image

[image]

Notice that all these data graphs blend but I just need them to occlude each other, while the overlapped parts don't draw at all for performance.

## Attempts

I could use a new path to only draw the difference, but I'm not sure this is the easiest way.

I checked `RepaintBoundary` but it's a widget that handles infrequent data  changes, not exactly what I need here.

Similarly `Overlay` seems a standalone widget, so I don't know how to fit it into `CustomPaint`.

### Question

Is there a standard way to achieve the occlusion I need?

Comment: Can you add some images for reference?

Comment: @dev-aentgs I updated the question. Will it help?

Comment: The image helped, cannot think of a solution yet. Maybe using `union` [PathOperation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/PathOperation-class.html) in `canvas.drawPath( Path.combine(` might help but not sure.